# JSF performance/threading issue with composite components

Tags: performance, jsf, primefaces, composite-component, mojarra

We have an application stack using mojarra (2.1.18-jboss)/primefaces(3.4.2) with composite components (mainly some tags) for all page level components.

When executing volume testing we noticed that very soon after starting execution instead of a nice load spread across all CPU's on the server (it would run liek this initially) all the traffic would be loaded onto a single maxed out processor and throughput would reduce to a crawl with steadily increasing response times.

In order to debug we tried a number of approaches removing various service of the application architecture, eventually removing the composite components themselves. With a pure PrimeFaces page the issue does not appear.

we re-introduced a simple CC wrapping a commandButton (see below) and have found that just the targetable attribute causes this issue to occur.

Has anyone else come across this issue or similar when using CC with Mojarra (note the page is not particularly big in component terms - maybe 1-200 components or so)..?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
<composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="styleClass" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="layoutClass" required="true"
                default="standard1Column" />
        <composite:attribute name="buttonAction"
                method-signature="java.lang.String action()" targets="CommandButtonID"
                targetAttributeName="action" />
        <composite:attribute name="buttonActionListener"
                method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)"
                targets="CommandButtonID" targetAttributeName="actionListener" />
        <composite:attribute name="ajax" default="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="disabled" default="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="update" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="process" required="false" default="@form" />
        <composite:attribute name="immediate" required="false" default="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="icon" required="false" />
        <composite:attribute name="tabindex" required="false" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

                <p:commandButton id="CommandButtonID"
                        value="button"
                        title="button"
                        ajax="#{cc.attrs.ajax}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        update="#{cc.attrs.update}" process="#{cc.attrs.process}"
                        immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"
                        tabindex="#{cc.attrs.tabindex}"
                />
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated...

Comment: We had also problems with jboss 2.1.13 and it was heavy loading our production server. In 2.1.1x versions i think there is some bug when you are using composite components. All composite attributes are added in list but they are never removed from list or something like that ( if i remember correctly ). So you can try to upgrade to 2.1.23 or something ... ( hope that this will help you or anyone in future who will face with same issues )